# how to move an existing git repository to an outer directory of a new project

Tags: git, github

I started a python coding project with the following directory structure

```
python_proj
 .git
 .gitignore
 some_dir
  some_file
 some_file
 ...
```

now I had to shift to the django web framework in which the *python_proj* becomes a subdirectory of *django_proj*

```
django_proj
 manage.py
 django_proj
  some_file
 python_proj (with above structure)
 ...
```

how do I "move" the .git repo of *python_proj* to the outer diectory *django_proj* to keep the history of *python_proj* and the "moved" repo becomes the repo of the complete project *django_proj*?
note: *django_proj* has no git repo. it is brand new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either move elements within the existing `python_proj` repo, and end up with only one git repo.

```
cd /path/to/python_proj
mkdir python_proj
git mv * python_proj
git commit -m "reorg"
cp files for django
git add -A .
git commit -m "django"
# rename root folder in django_proj
```

Or, and that would be my preferred approach, you could declare the `python_proj` as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of the new `django_proj`:

```
cd /path/to/django_proj
git add -A .
git commit -m "all django files, except python proj"
git submodule add /url/of/python_proj
git commit -m "new python_proj submodule "
```

That way, both projects can evolve independently one from another, and `django_proj` would reference a fixed version of `python_proj`.

Comment: thanks for the 2 alternatives. applied the 1st one. I liked the submodule approach. I will tackle it in the near future ;)

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't "know" what the outer directory containing the `.git` metadata directory is called. You can rename it if you'd like and your repo would still work fine. Since your `django_proj` doesn't already have a git history, I'd recommend doing the following:

- Rename the outer directory `python_proj` to `django_proj`.
- Create a new directory, `django_proj/python_proj`, and add it using `git add`.
- `git mv * python_proj`
- Either move your django files into place and `git add` them, or just reinit django in the `django_proj` directory and add the new files.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't move it "out", rather move your files in a new directory.
In your `python_proj` directory create another  directory `python_proj`, then move all files you need to have in the Python project from current level to that directory using git:

```
mkdir python_proj
git mv some_dir python_proj
git mv some_file python_proj
...
git ci -m "Moved stuff"
```

Now you can just rename the outer directory (that is git root, i.e. contains .git). This won't affect the repository but you will have to update references to that repo in any apps you might be using (SourceTree etc.)

You'll probably need to review your `.gitignore` file content if you leave it on root level (I suppose you will). If you have any relative paths there, they should be updated as well.